# Type mismatch error message given #N/A #N/A for Calculation in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list (strongly simplified):

```
Quantity      Price          Volume
20            10
50            5
40            #N/A #N/A
20            #N/A #N/A
10            30
```

I have used the following lines of code to calculate volume:

```
For i = 1 to 5
Cells(i,3).Value = Cells(i,2).Value * Cells(i,1).Value
Next i
```

I get the type error message when I calculate the above, which I believe has to do with the "#N/A #N/A" error messages I am getting. Any suggestions on how I could circumvent this problem. Like for example, simply skipping the calculation if one the cells equal #N/A #N/A

Comment: `If Not IsError(cells(1,2)) then`

Answer (score 2):

The `*` multiplication operator expects operands it can work with, i.e. numeric values.

`[ActiveSheet.]Cells(i, 3).Value` returns a `Variant` that will wrap a `String` given a string cell value, a `Date` given a date value, a `Double` given a numeric value... and an `Error` given an error value.

While VBA is generally very permissive with types and merrily converts a `Date` to its `Double` representation, it can't implicitly convert the `Variant/Error` subtype to anything.

So any time you read a cell's value *without checking if it contains an error*, you're making an assumption about its data type, and when that assumption is wrong, a *type mismatch* error occurs.

The solution is to verify whether the `Variant` subtype involved is an `Error` value - the `IsError` function is perfect for this.

Pull the values into local variables, then use `IsError` to conditionally multiply the operands:

```
Dim lhs As Variant
lhs = ActiveSheet.Cells(i,2).Value

Dim rhs As Variant
rhs = ActiveSheet.Cells(i,1).Value

If Not IsError(lhs) And Not IsError(rhs) Then
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i,3).Value = lhs * rhs
Else
    'one of the operands is an error; can't compute...
End If
```